# How to delete one tag after the match is found

Tags: xml, shell

I am stuck in one situation like this where 2 XML tags are coming one after other in random pattern in a file . For EG:

Some tags ......

```
<ServiceConfig Id ="403">
<ServiceConfig Id ="345">
```

whereas I need only the second occurencce of TAG ServiceConfig ID wherever it is repeating.
Like for above eg I need

```
<ServcieConfig Id ="345">.
```

How can I do that i.e how can I delete all the repititive ServiceConfig Tags ?

PS.- The Id no is different for all the tags which are repititive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script language or even XSLT for that. However both solutions would need to use xpath to address the nodes of interest, I'm using this one:

```
//ServiceConfig[name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = "ServiceConfig"]
```

It selects all nodes where the previous sibling is also a `ServiceConfig` node.

---

Will now show how to remove that nodes using 1. XSLT and 2. Python. For the example I've used the following xml file:

*test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <node>
    <sub id="1" />
    <some />
    <sub id="2" />
  </node>
  <node>
    <some />
    <sub id="3" />
    <sub id="4" />
  </node>
</data>
```

**XSLT based solution**

*delete.xsl*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="//sub[name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'sub']">
    <!-- empty, leads to tag removal -->
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- identy transformation of the remaing node -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Execute it:

```
xsltproc delete.xsl test.xml
```

**Python based solution**

*delete.py*

```py
import libxml2

doc = libxml2.parseFile("test.xml")
ctx = doc.xpathNewContext()
res = ctx.xpathEval("//sub[name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'sub']")

for item in res:
    item.unlinkNode()

print doc
```

Execute it:

```
python delete.py
```

Output of both solutions is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <node>
    <sub id="1"/>
    <some/>
    <sub id="2"/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <some/>
    <sub id="3"/>

  </node>
</data>
```

You can fix the blank line using a *pretty printer*, I've omitted that for brevity.

Comment: It is showing an error as : Unknown option --xpath. Also, multiple occurrence of these pairs of tag is there and we need to remomove the 1st tag from each of them.

Comment: Which version of xmllint are you using? you probably would need to upgrade or compile manually using `--with-xpath`. Updated the xpath query.